# What is the reason I am getting: Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing c sockets the send a file from client to server.  `client()` is called in main client program while the `server()` is called in the server program. `send_file()` is a helper function for `client()`.  I want the server to wait for another client connection after it finishes getting data from the current client.
The first iteration is fine but I am getting error from `accept` in the SECOND iteration in the server: `server: accept: Socket operation on non-socket`
What causes the problem?

```
int send_file(int socket, char *path) {
    int len;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    char size[BUF_SIZE];
    struct stat stbuf;

    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    fstat(fd, &stbuf);
    sprintf(size, "%d", (int)stbuf.st_size);

    write(socket, size, BUF_SIZE);
    while((len = read(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
        write(socket, buf, len);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 1;
}

int client(char *src_path, char *dest_path, char *host_ip, int port) {

    int sock_fd;
    // Create the sock fd
    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_fd < 0) {
        perror("client: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the IP and port of the server to connect to.
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, host_ip, &server.sin_addr) < 1) {
        perror("client: inet_pton");
        close(sock_fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Connect to the server
    if (connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        perror("client: connect");
        close(sock_fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    send_file(sock_fd, src_path);

    return 0;
}

int server(int port) {
    printf("PORT: %d\n", port);

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int sock_fd, client_fd;
    int len;

    // Create the socket FD.
    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_fd < 0) {
        perror("server: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set information about the port (and IP) we want to be connected to.
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&server.sin_zero, 0, 8);

    // Bind the selected port to the socket
    if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("server: bind");
        close(sock_fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Announce willingness to accept connections on this socket
    if (listen(sock_fd, MAX_BACKLOG) < 0) {
        perror("server: listen");
        close(sock_fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        socklen_t client_size = sizeof(client);
        if ((client_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_size)) < 0) {
            perror("server: accept");
            close(sock_fd);
            exit(1);
        }

        read(client_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        int size = atoi(buf);
        printf("Size: %d\n", size);

        while ((size > 0) && ((len = read(client_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)) {
            size -= len;
            buf[len] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buf);
        }

       close(client_fd);
    }

    close(sock_fd);

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and see what the value of `sock_fd` is before and after the accept? Also cannot see where `client` is declared...?

Comment: If you mean the struct in `rcopy_server`, it is defined with the `struct sockaddr_in server, client;` on line 74

Comment: I did and now that you've pointed it out, I can clearly see it! The debugging suggestion still stands tho

Comment: Never mind - Jeremy's answer has found what I suspected was happening but hadn't spotted yet.

Comment: Please do not deface your question! It is important that it contains the actual code where the error is happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow in your read code on the server.

```
    while ((size > 0) && ((len = read(client_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)) {
        size -= len;
        buf[len] = '\0';
        //  ^^^ Boom!!!
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
```

If you read `BUF_SIZE` bytes from the socket, `len` is `BUF_SIZE` and then you set the byte at buf[BUF_SIZE] to `\0`. This must be clobbering the socket file descriptor which is declared straight after the buffer.

I should add, the best way to fix it is probably to declare the buffer with size `BUF_SIZE + 1` rather than read `BUF_SIZE - 1` bytes because the IO will be a bit more efficient (you are writing in `BUF_SIZE` chunks).

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I don't actually need that line for my program and I have forgotten it.

Comment: Just put 'BUF_SIZE-1' in for the read length and keep the NUL write.  It's much safer, since read is not guaranteed to load data that is NUL-terminated.:)

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I just added what I consider to be the slightly better fix to the answer. Since she is writing in BUF_SIZE chunks, it's probably more efficient to read in BUF_SIZE chunks into a buffer that is big enough to hold BUF_SIZE bytes + the `\0`. I gues sit is marginal though.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The terminating null is not useless, without it the following `printf` will overrun because `buf` is treated as a string parameter.

Comment: @JeremyP: the null terminator is not needed at all if `len` is passed as an input parameter to `printf()` so it knows when to stop printing, eg: `while ((size > 0) && ((len = read(client_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)) { size -= len; printf("%.*s", len, buf); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau true but I'd probably just do a back to back [fwrite()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm)